# Testing Angular component extending an abstract class

Tags: angular, jestjs, angular-components, angular-test, ngxs

I have this setup for a number of components:

```
@Directive()
export abstract class BaseComponent implements OnInit {

   @Select(PortalState.portal) public portalState: Observable<PortalModel>;
   public portal: PortalModel;
   protected ngUnsubscribe: Subject<void> = new Subject();

   constructor(
     protected someService: SomeService,
     protected route: ActivatedRoute
     ){
   }

   public ngOnInit(): void {
     this.route.params
     .pipe(
        filter(res => !!res),
        tap(res => this.id = res['id']),
        switchMap(() => this.portalState),
        takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
     )
     .subscribe(res => {
        this.portal = res;
        this.afterInit();
     });
   }

   public ngOnDestroy(): void {
       this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
       this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
   }

   public abstract afterInit(): void
}
```

and then in every component which extends this base class:

```
@Component({...})
export class SomeComponent extends BaseComponent {

   public specificVar: any;

   constructor(
     protected someService: SomeService,
     protected route: ActivatedRoute
   ){
      super(someService, route);
   }

   public afterInit(): void {
     /** do component specific stuff */
     this.specificVar = 'something';
   }

}
```

Now it works fine, however when testing, the abstract component's ngOnInit seems to be not called at all rendering (in this example) `this.specific` variable as undefined.

the spec file looks quite traditional

```
let store: Store; /** Ngxs store */
const mockPortalModel: PortalModel = {id: 1};

beforeEach(async () => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule(/** providers and usual setup */);
  store = TestBed.inject(Store);
  store.reset({
    portalState: mockPortalModel
  });
  jest.spyOn(store, 'dispatch');
  jest.spyOn(store, 'select');
});

beforeEach(() => {
   fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SomeComponent);
   component = fixture.componentInstance;
   fixture.detectChanges();
});
```

Any ideas why `ngOnInit` and subsequently `afterInit` are not being called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in `this.route.params` which had to be mocked, so the subscription could fire. So mocking activated route has solved the issue:

```
const mockActivatedRoute = {
  snapshot: {}, // needs to be there to avoid _lastPathIndex error
  params: of({id: 123})
}

/** ...  */
providers: [
  {provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: mockActivatedRoute }
]
```

had ensured that the subscription goes through (see that `filter(res => !!res)` - it stopped right there).

Answer (score 0):

You have to write below function in your `SomeComponent` so that it will run your `BaseComponent`'s `ngOnInit` method after `SomeComponent`'s `ngOnInit` method.

```
ngOnInit() {
  super.ngOnInit();
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's true. The component compiles and works fine on itself. It is just about testing it where it fails.